# Split text between brackets in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, split, nsstring

I need to split the text (NSString), that looks like this:

`[text],[more text here].`

How do I store in a String[] the two texts between brackets, separated by a ","?

Comment: So you want your output to be `text, more text here`? as a single string?

Comment: You probably don't want to use a C array of strings but rather an `NSArray`.

Comment: I´ve tried to use componentSeparatedByString, but did not work so well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using a regular expression and `NSRegularExpression`.

Construct a pattern which matches the text between brackets. For example the pattern `@"\\[([^]]*)]"` matches an opening bracket `\\[` - the backslash is required to treat the bracket as a literal character, zero or more characters except a closing bracket `[^]]*`, groups that text so it referred to `([^]]*)`, and a closing bracket `]`. You can build up a pattern which matches comma separated sequences of bracket text, or just look for multiple matches of bracketed text - depending on your requirements.

Once you've created your regular expression, using the method`regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:`, the method `matchesInString:options:range:` can be used obtain an array of all the matches. You can process this array to produce your required array of strings.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, i've searched for the concept of Regular Expressions in iOS and i figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * result = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray * commaSeparatedParenthesizedStrings = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSCharacterSet * bracketsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"];
forin (NSString * s in commaSeparatedParenthesizedStrings) {
  [result addObject:[s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:bracketsToTrim]];
}
```

Please note that this solution does not account for commas *within* the parentheses, and furthermore will trim all parentheses from the input, so `[[[[[]][[]]hello][][[[][][]][][], [[][[][]world[[]][[]][]]` would return `@[@"hello", @"world"]`

The NSScanner solution above, or one like it, should be more robust for ensuring that commas within parentheses are avoided when splitting the input string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
  NSString *testString = @"[more],[more te,xt here],[],[,,,,],[text3]";
  NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"],["];
  NSString *text = @"";

  for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++){
    NSString *word = [array objectAtIndex: i];
    NSString *aux = @"";
    NSRange range;
    if(i == 0){
      range = NSMakeRange(1, word.length - 1);
    }
    else{
      aux = @",";
      if(i == array.count - 1)
        range = NSMakeRange(0, word.length - 1);
      else
        range = NSMakeRange(0, word.length);
    }
    aux = [aux stringByAppendingString:
      [word substringWithRange:range]];
    text = [text stringByAppendingString:aux];
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",text);
```