# Storing multiple values from one text field into an array

Tags: arrays, macos, cocoa, text, swift

I have one text field but I want to be able to store the multiple values entered in that text field (eg. 1,2,3,4) stored into an array. So far, all it does is store it all as one element that still has the commas. How can I get rid of the commas and store each value separately?

Comment: You have to split the text into numbers using NSRegularExpression. See accepted answer here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721368/objective-c-split-text-between-brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use global `split` function which works on any `Sequence` (including `String`):

If you want it to be separated by commas only:

```
let array = split("x,y,z") { $0 == "," }
```

If you'd want to separate by either commas or spaces:

```
let array = split("x, y z") { contains(", ", $0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string method componentsSeparatedByString(separator: String) -> [String]
For example:

```
let example = "1,2,3,4"
let elements =  textfieldValue.componentsSeparatedByString(",") // elements is an array with Strings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below :-

```
 NSArray *valueArr=[[yourTextfield stringValue] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```